# Create memory dump from the windows commandline

Tags: windows, forensics, memory, volatility

I was following [this](http://kromer.pl/malware-analysis/memory-forensics-using-volatility-toolkit-to-extract-malware-samples-from-memory-dump/) blog post to dump the memory of a windows host. Sadly this method does not work on Windows Server 2012 because the memory drivers that come with mdd aren't signed and this is required in newer windows version.

Is there a known way to get around this problem without using a GUI?

Comment: I was trying to do the same and someone pointed me to the usage of the built in Werfault.exe

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: As far as I remember, [WinPmem](https://github.com/google/rekall/releases) does not require a GUI.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? If so, take a snapshot and convert it to a memory image. Another option is to configure the OS to perform a full memory dump and create a BSOD yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing a memory dump, you can use **DumpIt** and read the dump with volatility.